# Meaning of an idiomatic expression

Tags: meaning

What does it mean "take it for granted" Please, give me an example of how to use it. Thank you

Comment: Hi @Francisco, Welcome to ELU. When asking questions, please include information regarding any research done prior to posting. For a common phrase such as _Take it for granted_, finding information online should be fairly effortless.

Comment: @Francisco maybe you will prefer [English Learners StackExchange](https://ell.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 2):

To "take something for granted" is to accept something without second thought.

---

Maybe google will help

[image: take for granted]

> ## take for granted
>
> 1. fail to properly appreciate (someone or something), especially as a result of overfaimilarity.
> 2. assume that something is true without questioning it.

---

1. Basically, it means that something is not being thought about or recognised/appreciated enough because the people who are using it expect it to be always available:

> We all take food for granted, but think of the farmers and workers who toil for hours to provide it to us.

2. Be told a fact and not question it, could be because you are gullible or because it seems obvious to you.

> I took it for granted that the Earth is round. It just seems so obvious doesn't it? Although, I've never looked at it myself...

Comment: A comma after your first "that" helps slightly ;)

Comment: This is a good, detailed answer. But unfortunately the question is not as good. It's highly likely that such questions might get closed and soon deleted. :)